# Android - Resume app when open it from CH Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app with 2 activities A and B, A have a button to open B and finish itself (B with lauchmode=singletop).
When app show activity B, i can resume app from click icon app. I uploaded my app to CH Play, and when i click "open app" from CH Play, app not resume, it show activity A.
I tested some other app on CH Play got same issue. Have any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding below line in onCreate of activity A.

```
if(!isTaskRoot()) finish();
```